# How to enable vue lazy loading when the app is served from a CDN?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, netlify

I am working on a project with an isolated frontend and backend. The backend is a Laravel app serving the APIs and the frontend is a VueJS app consuming those APIs.

The backend app is deployed on a digitalocean droplet, and the frontend app is deployed on netlify. However, the end-users do not hit the Vue app. The Laravel app has an env variable called `ASSET_URL` where I've assigned the netlify URL. I've then added the script and link tags pointing to the resources (`/js`, `/css`) of `/dist` directory of the Vue app to my main *Laravel view file* that gets returned from the Laravel app:

```
// app.blade.php
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{config('app.asset_url') . '/css/app.css'}}">
...
<script src="{{config('app.asset_url') . '/js/app.js'}}"></script>
<script src="{{config('app.asset_url') . '/js/app.chunk.js'}}"></script>
...
```

In the Vue app, I have overridden the default webpack configuration in the vue.config.js file so that webpack does not insert the [contentHash] in the filenames which makes it easier to inject the static resources into the Laravel app:

```
// vue.config.js

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        disableHostCheck: true,
        port: '8080'
    },
    chainWebpack: config => {
        if (config.plugins.has('extract-css')) {
            const extractCSSPlugin = config.plugin('extract-css')
            extractCSSPlugin && extractCSSPlugin.tap(() => [{
                filename: 'css/app.css',
                chunkFilename: 'css/app.chunk.css'
            }])
        }
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: false
        },
        output: {
            filename: 'js/app.js',
            chunkFilename: 'js/app.chunk.js'
        }
    }
}
```

Long story short, from the end-users perspective, the Vue app does not exist.

But the problem is, now I have lost the ability to lazy load the routes, because if I use the `/* webpackChunkname: "product" */` magic comment in my route definition like this:

```
component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "product" */ "@/views/product/ProductList.vue")
```

Then Webpack will throw an error:

> conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename (app.chunk.js)

So I've gone ahead and made the following changes to my `vue.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        host: "0.0.0.0",
        disableHostCheck: true,
        port: '8080'
    },
    chainWebpack: config => {
        if (config.plugins.has('extract-css')) {
            const extractCSSPlugin = config.plugin('extract-css')
            extractCSSPlugin && extractCSSPlugin.tap(() => [{
                filename: 'css/app.css',
                chunkFilename: 'css/[name].css'
            }])
        }
    },
    configureWebpack: {
        output: {
            filename: 'js/app.js',
            chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js'
        }
    }
}
```

This is what the build files look like:

```
  dist/js/chunk-vendors.js                                      2083.74 KiB                             607.00 KiB
  dist/js/app.js                                                1548.29 KiB                             259.22 KiB
  dist/js/chunk-b0a634c6.js                                     287.19 KiB                              96.31 KiB
  dist/js/product.js                                            7.51 KiB                                2.43 KiB
  dist/precache-manifest.78cd95684ece42546415aacd7f68cced.js    2.43 KiB                                0.86 KiB
  dist/service-worker.js                                        1.04 KiB                                0.61 KiB
  dist/css/app.css                                              419.79 KiB                              60.69 KiB
  dist/css/chunk-vendors.css
```

And I am injecting the resources to my laravel app like this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{config('app.asset_url') . '/css/app.css'}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{config('app.asset_url') . '/css/chunk-vendors.css'}}">
</head>
…
<script src="{{config('app.asset_url') . '/js/app.js'}}"></script>
<script src="{{config('app.asset_url') . '/js/chunk-vendors.js'}}"></script>
<script src="{{config('app.asset_url') . '/js/chunk-b0a634c6.js'}}"></script>
<script src="{{config('app.asset_url') . '/js/product.js'}}"></script>
```

To test this set up locally, my laravel app is being served from
`test.myapp.test`, and the vue app is being served from `localhost:8080`. So I have assigned `http://localhost:8080` to the `ASSET_URL`.

I have two problems now:

1. On initial load, all the the resources including `product.js` are loading even when I am not on that route. That is because I've hard-coded the script/link tags. And it defeats the purpose of lazy loading (load only when I'm on that route)
2. When I visit the /product route, the application does look for the `product.js` file lazily, but instead of looking for http://localhost/8080/js/product.js, it is looking for http://test.myapp.test/js/product.js, so I end up getting the following error:

> vue-router.esm.js?8c4f:2257 ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk product failed.
> (missing: http://test.myapp.test/js/product.js)

How do I lazy load routes or what modifications do I need in my webpack config so that the lazy loaded components are searched in the ASSET_URL instead of the current host?

[Even if you have a better idea to lazy load routes when using a CDN, it would be extremely helpful if you please share it]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look on the below package

https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-lazyload

OR

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-clazy-load

wherein for images all you need to do is pass the local/cloud path and the rest is handled by the package itself